# Use PowerShell to include/exclude text between nth one character and nth different character in all lines

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with lots of lines like these:

```
BALL - A 5122-ABCD-STH-PC2016/A 5122 : It's a duplicate.
CIRCLE - B 612-DEFGH-STH-LAPTOP2005/B 612 : It's a duplicate.
```

What I want to do with PowerShell, is to extract the text between the `3rd space` and `3rd hyphen` (don't include the delimiters), The 3rd hyphen goes after the 3rd space. Do this for all lines. Like this:

```
5122-ABCD
612-DEFGH
```

The `sed`, `awk` and `cut` equivalents are:

```
cat file.txt | sed -E 's/^([^ ]*[ ]){3}//' | sed -E 's/(^([^-]*[-]){1}[^-]*).*/\1/'
cat file.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $4}' | awk -F'-' '{print $1 "-" $2}'
cat file.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 4- | cut -d '-' -f -2
```

But ideally I should introduce the number for the nth occurrence of the space and the hyphen instead of "hard coding" it. And compatible with any version of PowerShell.

Related topics:

- [Print everything after nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650424/print-everything-after-nth-delimiter)
- [Print everything before nth delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761483/73244)

Comment: isnt that 3rd space 2nd hyphen ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon no, that would be `5122` 

and `612`.

Comment: I meant like after the 3rd space and after the 2nd appearance of a hyphen mm maybe I misunderstood, but something like this: https://regex101.com/r/JwYBRw/1

Comment: Don't include the delimiters I've edited the question.

Comment: something like this then https://regex101.com/r/JwYBRw/3 would match exactly what you want then the numbers between `{..}` can be dynamically updated

Comment: Yeah that does it perfectly, why don't you add a new answer? Also add how to use it with `grep` or `sed`, your answer is very good.

Comment: mmm why use `grep` or `sed` when powershell has full access to .net and .net comes with its own regex engine? I can add my answer but I really dont see the point of using `grep` or `sed` at all.

Comment: Just for curiosity, would like to know how to use it with sed or grep: `sed 's/(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})(?:[^-]+-){1}[^-]+//gm' file.txt` or `grep '(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})(?:[^-]+-){1}[^-]+' file.txt`

Comment: no idea, never used those, never had a need. probably they don't support something like `(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})` either

Comment: So where are you supposed to use those regular expressions, are for Perl or Python, PHP....?

Comment: those patterns are for any .NET language (and powershell is one of those). See, .NET has its own regex engine: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

An almost literal translation from awk to powershell:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
    ($line.split(" ")[3]).split("-")[0]+"-"+($line.split(" ")[3]).split("-")[1]
}
```

Comment: How do you add `sort` and `get-unique` to it?

Comment: Just add `|Sort-Object -Unique` like is done in the other anwers ?

Comment: Yes that does it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to combine [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) (in both its unary and binary forms) and [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join), along with the ability of PowerShell's index operator ([`[...]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#index-operator--) to accept *multiple* indices (elements) to return from an array.

```bash
# Sample array of input strings - replace with `Get-Content file`
@(
  "BALL - A 5122-ABCD-STH-PC2016/A 5122 : It's a duplicate."
  "CIRCLE - B 612-DEFGH-STH-LAPTOP2005/B 612 : It's a duplicate."
) | 
  ForEach-Object { ((-split $_)[3] -split '-')[0, 1] -join '-' } |
  Sort-Object -Unique  # > file-sorted.txt
```

- `-split $_` uses the unary form of `-split` to split each line by *nonempty run of whitespace* (ignoring any leading or trailing whitespace)
- `(...)[3] -split '-'` then extracts the 4th token and splits it by `-`
- `[0, 1]` extracts the first 2 `-`-separated tokens from the result and joins them with `-` to form a single string.

Comment: Very good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3) and a regex pattern to extract those values:

```bash
$text = @'
BALL - A 5122-ABCD-STH-PC2016/A 5122 : It's a duplicate.
CIRCLE - B 612-DEFGH-STH-LAPTOP2005/B 612 : It's a duplicate.
'@

$text | Select-String '(?m)(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})(?:[^-]+-){1}[^-]+' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Or, if you want to use the [`regex` api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0) directly:

```bash
[regex]::Matches($text, '(?m)(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})(?:[^-]+-){1}[^-]+') |
    ForEach-Object Value |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Regex details on https://regex101.com/r/JwYBRw/3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way thanks to [Month of PowerShell: Cut a Column of Text](https://www.sans.org/blog/month-of-powershell-cut-a-column-of-text/):

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object { $elements = $_ -split '-'; $elements[1]+"-"+$elements[2] } | ForEach-Object { $elements = $_ -split ' '; $elements[2] } | sort | get-unique | out-file file-sorted.txt
```

It also sorts it and removes duplicates, and saves the result to another file.

Using the @SantiagoSquarzon answer:

```
$file = $Args[0]
$text = Get-Content $file
$text | Select-String '(?m)(?<=^(?:\S+\s){3})(?:[^-]+-){1}[^-]+' -AllMatches |
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving the solution of @santiago-squarzon:

- Patterns placed in variables
- nth match for each pattern in variables
- Regular expression to be used is printed to standard output
- Results from applying the filter are printed to standard output if no output file is given, else saved to it instead.

`filter.ps1`:

```
$file = $Args[0]
$text = Get-Content $file

$SELECT_STRING = '(?m)(?<=^(?:\S+P1){N1})(?:[^P2]+P2){N2}[^P2]+'

$P1 = "\s"
$P2 = "-"
$P3 = "/"
$N1 = "3"
$N2 = "1"

$SELECT_STRING = $SELECT_STRING.Replace('P1',$P1)
$SELECT_STRING = $SELECT_STRING.Replace('P2',$P2)
$SELECT_STRING = $SELECT_STRING.Replace('N1',$N1)
$SELECT_STRING = $SELECT_STRING.Replace('N2',$N2)

Write-Host "regex: '$SELECT_STRING'"

$result = @($text | Select-String $SELECT_STRING -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
    Sort-Object -Unique)

if (!$args[1]) {
  $result | Out-Host
} else {
  $result | Out-File $args[1]
}
```